# PowerShell - Match getting wrong file

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following code:

```
$MoveSheet0101AfterRender = get-ChildItem $Sheet01 -recurse | where {$_.name -match "Model 01-02 - $TodayDate"} | Move-Item -Destination (new-item -type directory -force ($OldSheets + $newSub)) -force -ea 0
```

Basically it asks PowerShell to look for files with `Model 01-02 - $TodayDate` in the name and move these files to the directory defined in `$OldSheets`, but for some reason it is copying files that have a slight variation in the name.

For example: if the file is named `Model 01-03 - $TodayDate`, for some reason the script is moving too.

I tried changing `-match` to `-contains`, but that way no files were moved.

Remembering that `Model 01-02 - $TodayDate` is just a part of the file name, for this reason I cannot use `-eq`.

How can I resolve this?

**Update:**

I have another variable called `$MoveSheet0103AfterRender` and its code is this:

```
$MoveSheet0103AfterRender = get-ChildItem $Sheet01 -recurse | where {$_.name -eq "$ClientName - Modelo 01-03 - $TodayDate.txt"} | Move-Item -Destination (new-item -type directory -force ($OldSheets + $newSub)) -force -ea 0
```

What seems to be happening is that this variable is being executed even though it's not in the code, because when I delete it the code works as expected.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Your first example should work since `02` compared to `03` are not the same when it comes to RegEx matching. Why dont you use the filesystem filtering with `-Filter` instead? Regarding your update, can you clarify on that some more?

Comment: Perfect, the first example seems to work now. The issue is that for some reason the variable `$MoveSheet0103AfterRender` seems to be applied to code, even without actually being applied in the code, It is just a variable that has not been assigned anywhere, which is a little strange. I deleted the variable `$MoveSheet0103AfterRender` and asked to run the script again, so the script worked correctly and didn't move the file `Model 01-03 - $TodayDate.txt` only `Model 01-02 - $TodayDate.txt`

Comment: You might think "Why did you create the variable if you're not using it?", and the answer is that I haven't gotten to that part of the code yet, I just created the variables to make the process easier.

Comment: As for the -Filters parameter, what do you recommend? I'm a beginner, so I do a lot of things based on trial and error, I'm groping until I get the result... any suggestion and learning is very welcome!